# What is the base_reachable_time (ARP related) proc entry

Tags: linux-kernel, arp, proc

As per arp(7) - Linux man page :

> base_reachable_time (since Linux 2.2)
>       Once a neighbor has been found, the entry is considered to be valid for at least a random value between base_reachable_time/2 and
>   3*base_reachable_time/2. **An entry's validity will be extended if it
>   receives positive feedback from higher level protocols.** Defaults to 30
>   seconds. This file is now obsolete in favor of base_reachable_time_ms.
>   base_reachable_time_ms (since Linux 2.6.12)
>       As for base_reachable_time, but measures time in milliseconds. Defaults to 30000 milliseconds.

I did not understand this explanation - especially the statement about the positive feed back from higher level protocols. Somebody please clarify ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [arp(7) man page](http://linux.die.net/man/7/arp),

> When there is no positive feedback for an existing mapping after some
>   time (see the /proc interfaces below), a neighbor cache entry is
>   considered stale. Positive feedback can be gotten from a higher layer;
>   **for example from a successful TCP ACK. Other protocols can signal
>   forward progress using the MSG_CONFIRM flag to sendmsg(2).** When there
>   is no forward progress, ARP tries to reprobe.

Basically this means that if something like a continues TCP connection is happening with a lot of successful ACKs, then it assumes the IP/MAC pair it has is valid and doesn't bother doing a new ARP request when the entry in the table would normally expire.

Answer (score 1):

For IPv6, the function `ndisc_router_discovery` can update `base_reachable_time`.
The IPv6 neighbor discovery protocol (which replaces ARP) gets this information and updates it.